# Java : filling Object Array overflow into other fields

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, tetris

## Tetris Game

My code works as it should at the start but after some time playing it breaks. When a falling piece touches the ground and gets put into the gamefield it gets stretched up into other spaces.
the field Object(Block) only holds one variable "filled" and when `field[fallingPiece.getY() + y + fieldExtra][fallingPiece.getX() + x].setFilled(true);` gets executed it changes the state of multiple Objectses(Blockses) state in the field.

The `fieldExtra` variable is the non visible space above the game field where the pieces get spawned. Its value is 20.
Its interesting to note that the Bug doesn't fill the whole array but only to 19 after which it just stops.
Also interesting is that once the bug started it always occurs unless the piece gets placed under some height.

```
private static void placePiece() {
    Block[][] pieceField = fallingPiece.getPieceField();
    for(int y=0; y < pieceField.length; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x < pieceField[0].length; x++) {
            if(pieceField[y][x].isFilled()) {
                 field[fallingPiece.getY() + y + fieldExtra][fallingPiece.getX() + x].setFilled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to look at the entirety of the code here is my
[Github repository](https://github.com/BrotherTill/Tetris)

I have already looked at it in the debugger and I went step by step through the code and at `field[fallingPiece.getY() + y + fieldExtra][fallingPiece.getX() + x].setFilled(true);` it filled multiple Objects at the same time when executing. while the for loops are behaving as expected.

I have also found that when commenting out the collision detection with the field the bug doesn't happen anymore, which I don't understand because they don't correlate in any way.

EDIT: The Bug is solved and wasn't caused by the code snippet above.

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [mre] program, one that condenses your code and your problem into the smallest program possible, small enough to be allowed to be posted in your question as code-formatted text (not as a GitHub link), one that compiles and runs for us without modification, one that demonstrates your problem for us, and also that has no code that is not essential for the above. Please check out the link which explains what this useful tool is and how it can help both you and us.

Comment: I got it to error once, and now I can't seem to duplicate it.  Do you know how to produce the error?

Comment: The error seems to only happen after playing for some time(dropping around 40 pieces) and than it starts overflowing into other Blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Cause of the Bug it was the way I cleared lines:

```
field[y + fieldExtra] = field[y + fieldExtra - 1];
```

This just sets one line which is an Object[] to the line(Obeject[]) above it.
That linked the different Blocks in some way I think, I dont really understand how that works. But I fixed it and now it works with no Problems.

Here's the fix if you're interested:

```
for(int i=0; i < fieldWidth; i++) {
    field[y + fieldExtra][i].setFilled(field[y + fieldExtra - 1][i].isFilled());
}
```

Thanks for the help especially to [Hovercraft Full Of EelsHovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) for the tip to try and reproduce the Bug in a smaller Programm.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the bug is happening because the `fieldExtra` variable is being incremented by more than 1 for each iteration of the `for` loop. This is causing the `field` array to be accessed outside of its bounds, which is why multiple blocks are being modified when the `setFilled(true)` method is called.

To fix this, you can change the way that the `fieldExtra` variable is incremented. Instead of incrementing it by 1, you can increment it by the number of columns in the `pieceField` array. This will ensure that the `field` array is only accessed within its bounds

```
private static void placePiece() {
    Block[][] pieceField = fallingPiece.getPieceField();
    int fieldExtra = pieceField[0].length;
    for (int y = 0; y < pieceField.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < pieceField[0].length; x++) {
            if (pieceField[y][x].isFilled()) {
                field[fallingPiece.getY() + y + fieldExtra][fallingPiece.getX() + x].setFilled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no the fieldExtra variable doesnt get touched and is declared as final:
`private static final int fieldExtra = 20;`. The variable is there to ignore the space above the actual gamefield. where the new pieces get spawned. It is like the array is split in 2 the top half for spawning and just space and the bottom half for the actual game.
Also the Bug doesnt happen until some time passed playing as intended where the method does its job correctly.